# How to prove that $X$ is a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was trying to show a function is a random variable.  But I got confused. I could not identify the process. Can you please tell me how to solve it?

The function was

$$X(\omega)=\begin{cases}\omega &,\text{ if } 0\le \omega\le \frac12 \\\omega-\frac12 &,\text{ if } \frac12<\omega\le1\end{cases}$$

Is $X$ a random variable?

Comment: A "function" cannot be a "variable."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork in Probability, what are termed 'random variables' are defined rigorously as functions defined on a state space.

Comment: Please share your attempts. Have you tried to apply the definition of a random variable?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are taking the basic space to be $[0,1]$ with Borel sigma algebra and you want to prove measurability of $X$ defined by $X(w)=w$ for $0 \leq w \leq \frac  1 2$ and $X(w)=w-\frac  1 2 $ for $\frac  1 2< w \leq   1$ .  You can write $X$ as $YI_A+Z_B$ where $Y(w)=w$ for all $w$,$Z(w)=w-\frac  1 2$ for all $w$ and $A=[0,\frac 1 2],B=A^{c}$. Since $Y$ and $Z$ are continuous they are Borel measurable. $I_A$ and $I_B$ are measurable because $A$ is  a Borel set. Sums of measurable functions and products of measurable functions are measurable. Hence $X$ is measurable.

Comment: Thank you a lot